How can I calculate local time at different longitudes if I only know which longitudes have a local time of zero?
I have variables in a dataset that give me longitude[:], latitude[:], time[:] and localtime_at_0[time].
localtime_at_0 only tells me which longitudes are experiencing midnight. However, I'd like to know what time it is at all longitudes, so I can use that variable in another project. How might I go about this?
(Also, no need to include daylight savings or anything like that. I'm not prepared for that!)
ws  = Dataset('dataset.nc')

lon = ws.variables['longitude'][:]
time = ws.variables['time'][:]
loc0 = ws.variables['lon_lt0'][:] #based on time

###I don't think this part below is right! This is what a friend wrote, but I might scrap it.###
def calculation(lon, loc0):
  full_day = 24
  offset = len(lon) /360 * full_day
  loctime = loc0 + dt.timedelta(hours=offset)
  return loctime

for i in range(len(lon)): 
 loct = calculation(lon, loc0)
 print("{lon[i]}: {loct}")

I think there is a problem in my calculation, but I haven't gotten any further than that yet.

Why do you think that there is a problem in your calculation?

Please provide sample data indicating the format of your longitude values.  (i.e are they expressed in the form of a decimal number, are they expressed in degree, minute, second offset from UTC, are they expressed as +/- offset from UTC, or other?

Do you have any longitude value? In your description, you mentioned latitude as well. Do you have that value as well? Also as @itprorh66 mentioned, kindly provide sample values.
